# Volume group "vgubuntu" not found - Cannot run fsck

Tags: boot

I cannot boot my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (constantly stuck on loading nothing) and get the following error esc or any F key:
[Error on screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bov9S.jpg)

I tried to run fsck as asked or found in other answers, but nothing can be typed in. If I run over recovery mode I get the same error and the command lines are again ignored. How do I fix this? Via the grub? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Grub I do not think will be of any help with this disk error. Are you using some RAID configuration?

Comment: I do not thinks so, but if I run a hard disk check at startup I get an error that might suggest the harddrive is gone. Shall I try first to repair Ubuntu first with a disk?

Comment: If the hard drive is bad you will not be able to fix it in software need to replace the hard drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed myself this way:

- Made a bootable Ubuntu dvd and ran it.
- Went to "Try Ubuntu" mode and accessed with password laptop hard drives.
- Run `sudo fsck /dev/mpper/vgubuntu-root`and hit yes to all hard drive problems found.

This fixed the hard disk I guess by excluding somehow the bad sectors.

Comment: You can not over write bad sectors you can if possible move the data from bad sectors to other sectors and mark the bad spots.